# tabindex issue with custom select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I found this script from google. But it isn't working with **tabindex**. can you help me how to fix this.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/2/) link

js snippt:-

```
$('select').each(function () {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element
    $this.addClass('s-hidden');

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);
```

Comment: Kindly can you tell what exactly you are trying to achieve. You did not mention anywhere

Comment: this select box doesn't work with tabindex.

Comment: where is your tab code. so we can help u

Comment: what he means is that the new select box is not accessible via keyboard.. those events aren't there.. I see only `click` event being handled. Plus even before the select box works with keyboard, it needs to focus there.

Comment: just and example of what needs to be done... Not a complete fix.. but here it is.. http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/334/

Comment: @pjp i am not able to select option. You just open selectbox but keyboard up and down key doesn't work.

Comment: as i mentioned.. i didnt make the demo work completely..just gave you an idea of what is MISSING and WHAT YOU CAN DO to make sure that it works with keys

Answer (score 0):

Need to set tabindex dynamically with jQuery.

```
//Adds tabindex dynamically 
$this.attr("tabindex", "0");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elitownsend/BB3JK/4733/